# Loading imageview through Uri

Tags: android

I am putting uri path of my image in my intent from Activity A like this -

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageFileUri.getPath());
```

Then i get that Uri in Activity B

Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));

and then try to load this image in my activity but all i get is a black screen.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Does the URI parse properly?  There is so much information that you have not given us...

Comment: Ah apologies for that...I am not getting any exception at all. Yeah I am confused about the parsing of URI. I am not sure if I am doing it right. Look at my code above. please...

Comment: Well, looking at your code doesn't tell me much.  What is the String that you are passing to the Uri.parse(String) method??

Comment: I am passing the getPath() of one of my Uri

Comment: Ugh!  What are the contents of the String?!?!

Comment: Apologies for testing your patients... its /external/images/media/122
I know it is wrong..but what should i try to pass as string to parse

Comment: Is the image you are looking for on your device?  Or are you attempting to get it from the web?

Comment: it is on the device in the images folder of camera

Comment: Is it from the camera or is it an image you added when developing your application?

Answer (score 0):

for Uri.parse() to work you will have to have passed it as below

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageFileUri.toString());
```